# How is pressure reduced on the upper part of an aircrafts wing?

Tags: aircraft, lift

I have heard part of the explanation and that is that air on the top part of the aircrafts wing wants to move in a straight line, but the air is pulled down the slope or camber, but that's as far as I got. So why would pulling air downwards cause this pressure difference?

Comment: Air cannot be pulled (or pushed) by anything *other* than a pressure difference.

Comment: Ethan, maybe I've mentioned this to you before, but I would encourage you to read [*John Denker's on-line book about aviation*](http://www.av8n.com/how/). He just makes things so incredibly clear.